# How to find duplicate dependencies from pom.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection, pom.xml

**How to find duplicate dependencies from pom.xml**

This is my pom.xml.

I use spring-boot web application using maven.

I want to find duplicate jars and remove them.

How can I do that task? What are the duplicate jars and what is mean from afflict ID? These duplicate jars lost my project space and give errors.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>lk.slsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>slsi-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow Maven Webapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <scm>
            <connection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</connection>
            <url>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</url>
            <developerConnection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:mof_SriLanka/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow.git</developerConnection>
            <tag>1.0.0</tag>
        </scm>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <sonar.exclusions>**/public/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
            <!--</dependency>-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!--handle servlet-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!--<Email Dependency>-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
            </dependency>


            <!--Add mysql dependency-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <!--jasper-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.6</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.10</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>2.25.1</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: You don't have any duplicate artifact definitions in there. Could you specify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Ah.. My jax-rs web service works fine on the localhost... but in the server it gives error about databindig... so I added h2k plugings... can it be a error....

Comment: I don't know. You have to give us more information (the exact error message, the server configuration, difference to your local environment etc.)

Comment: @dunni ... this is my question .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616295/jax-rs-web-service-works-fine-on-localhost-fine-but-when-run-on-the-server-it-gi?noredirect=1#comment84229442_48616295

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found so far is to use the [apache enforcer](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) plugin:

1.) Add the maven enforcer plugin to your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2.) Enter in your cli (project path): `mvn enforcer:enforce`

3.) The output will be something like this:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 paths to dependency are:
+-com.stackoverflow.examples:EnforcerExample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.RC1
    +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.0.RC1
      +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.0.0.RC1
        +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
and
+-com.stackoverflow.examples:EnforcerExample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.2
]
```

Comment: Is this ok for my web service error... please give the answer for it...

Comment: Hi @vidarshana, this is the answer to your first question on 'how to find duplicate dependencies from pom.xml'. For your web service error, open another question and post the error message or/and stack trace. I will answer you!

Comment: I added a new question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655653/how-can-i-deploy-a-project-in-tomcat-server-with-dependenciesnew-dependencies