# How can I deploy a project in tomcat server with dependencies(new dependencies)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jax-rs, pom.xml

Hi I added my **Mavan Spring webapp to my server**.. I change some dependencies... The localhost works fine and when run on the server it gives the error... How can I download dependencies(build wih dependencies) in tomcat 8.5.11 to the server. I use the same version on the localhost and it works fine.

When I check WEB-INF/lib path in my server it shows the previous dependies... How can I download them...

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>


        <!--Add mysql dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image: **This is the jars on the server**]

Comment: @Kalaiselvan A How to do that

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: yes i use netbeans 8.2 ... I have an issue..See this link....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616295/jax-rs-web-service-works-fine-on-localhost-fine-but-when-run-on-the-server-it-gi?noredirect=1#comment84229442_48616295

Comment: I want to slove that problem

Comment: I dont have any issue in netbeans... I have an issue around my pom.... check the upper link

Comment: ok I clean it form the netbeans and redeploy.The localhost success..But in the server it occurs some errors...

Comment: @Kalaiselvan This is my error..Please check that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616295/jax-rs-web-service-works-fine-on-localhost-fine-but-when-run-on-the-server-it-gi?noredirect=1#comment84229442_48616295

Comment: @Kalaiselvan this is my server url for rest service... Please check out this https://nationalsinglewindow.gov.lk/SLSIonNationalSingleWindow/TransferPermit/SlsitoCustoms/getby/date/2018-02-02

Comment: Pls show your error logs...

Comment: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Cannot new create registration for component type class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$WebComponentBinder: Existing previous registration found for the type.

Comment: @KayV I got this error on the Server catalina out... But the webservice works fine on the localhost

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is some mis-match in the dependencies on the server.

This is how a web application looks for its dependencies:

1. First the dependencies are searched inside the web-inf/lib folder of the web application itself.
2. If not found, it will search it for in the lib of the tomcat.
3. If there is some conflicts in the dependencies, then an the web application does not starts.

The approach to resolve this should be:

Note: Keep the backup of all folders first.

1. Provide all the dependencies in the web-inf/lib folder.
2. If there is some issue, cut all the dependencies from web-inf/lib and paste in lib folder of tomcat. There could be some warnings for the duplicates or a dependency having multiple versions. In that case choose the best version which matches your requirements.
3. If still it does not works, copy the web-inf/lib and tomcat lib from the localhost and paste it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like versioning problem to me. Please check the jars in the lib folder, on local and on server and compare them. Specifically check, whats the version of **jersey-*.jar** files.

Another place you can check is the tomcat lib directory. what all jar are present in **local vs server**. Tomcat lib folder as used as "**provided**" dependency scope.